# Localization in Silverlight 4 application using PRISM

Tags: silverlight, localization, prism

I am new to silverlight development and PRISM framework. We are using http://happynet.codeplex.com/ as a template. The localization is working well if resource text is bind directly in XAML. But it is not working well for :

1. Texts in ViewModel Classes.
2. Grid Header Column Texts in View's Code behind.

They requires reloading after language switch. How can it be done so that text change occurs on language switch?

Comment: It is possible to change all the text without reloading? Never heard about it, I always reloaded application. But you can do what you want using C# events.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Happynet as it is the first time I see the project.

It depends how they implement localization but if you want dynamic localization (eg. selecting a language in a combobox) it can be done. Follow the following steps to set it up:

http://vanderbiest.org/blog/2009/11/30/silverlight-resource-files-localization-language-specification/

To dynamically change it, you just need to set the current UI thread.

```
static void SetLanguage(string culture)
    {
        if (culture != System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture.TextInfo.CultureName)
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo(culture);
        }
    }
```